# Multithreaded screen scraping help needed

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm relatively new to python, and I'm working through a screen- scraping application that gathers data from multiple financial sites. I have four procedures for now. Two run in just a couple minutes, and the other two... hours each. These two look up information on particular stock symbols that I have in a csv file. There are 4,000+ symbols that I'm using. I know enough to know that the vast majority of the time spent is in IO over the wire. It's essential that I get these down to 1/2 hour each (or, better. Is that too ambitious?) for this to be of any practical use to me. I'm using python 3 and BeautifulSoup.

I have the general structure of what I'm doing below. I've abbreviated conceptually non essential sections. I'm reading many threads on multiple calls/ threads at once to speed things up, and it seems like there are a lot of options. Can anyone point me in the right direction that I should pursue, based on the structure of what I have so far? It'd be a huge help. I'm sure it's obvious, but this procedure gets called along with the other data download procs in a main driver module. Thanks in advance...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import misc modules

class StockOption:
    def __init__(self, DateDownloaded, OptionData):
        self.DateDownloaded = DateDownloaded
        self.OptionData = OptionData

    def ForCsv(self):
        return [self.DateDownloaded, self.Optiondata]

def extract_options(TableRowsFromBeautifulSoup):
    optionsList = []
    for opt in range(0, len(TableRowsFromBeautifulSoup))
        optionsList.append(StockOption(data parsed from TableRows arg))
    return optionsList

def run_proc():
    symbolList = read in csv file of tickers
    for symb in symbolList:
        webStr = #write the connection string
        try:
            with urllib.request.urlopen(webStr) as url: page = url.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
            if soup.text.find('There are no All Markets results for') == -1:
                tbls = soup.findAll('table')
                if len(tbls[9]) > 1:
                    expStrings = soup.findAll('td', text=True, attrs={'align': 'right'})[0].contents[0].split()
                    expDate = datetime.date(int(expStrings[6]), int(currMonth), int(expStrings[5].replace(',', '')))
                    calls = extract_options(tbls[9], symb, 'Call', expDate)
                    puts = extract_options(tbls[13], symb, 'Put', expDate)
                    optionsRows = optionsRows + calls
                    optionsRows = optionsRows + puts

        except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
            if err.code == 404:
                pass
            else:
                raise
    opts = [0] * (len(optionsRows))
    for option in range(0, len(optionsRows)):
    opts[option] = optionsRows[option].ForCsv()
    #Write to the csv file.
    with open('C:/OptionsChains.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        a.writerows(opts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_proc()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in the abbreviated code you have given, so it is a little hard to understand the code. If you could show more code and check it, it will be easier to understand your problem.

From the code and problem description, I have some advice to share with you:

1. In `run_proc()` function, it read webpage for every symbol. If the urls are the same or some urls are repeated, how about read webpages for just one time and write them to memory or hardware, then analyze page contents for every symbol? It will save
2. `BeautifulSoup` is easy to write code, but a little slow in performance. If `lxml` can do your work, it will save a lot time on analyzing webpage contents.

Hope it will help.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure what mistakes you mean; some of the code is deliberately abbreviated, so this is not reproducible, no... but most of it is there, and it runs without error. Also.. none of the urls are the same; a different url is written in the loop, one for each unique symbol. I'll look into lxml, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed in the right direction from the following post (thanks to the authors btw):

[How to scrape more efficiently with Urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685552/how-to-scrape-more-efficiently-with-urllib2)